# Регулярное выражение для замены слова на ссылку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть строчка кода

```
$text=preg_replace('@пример@','<а href="#">пример</а>',$text);
```

Он меняет в тексте "пример" на ссылку. Но также может поменять из слова "примерное" его часть на ссылку. Что добавить в регулярку, что бы она меняла совпадение текста, но без букв по сторонам. А любые символы и цифры могут быть.

Comment: Уже ближе :) Но все ещё не то. Во первых при замене удаляет пробелы по бокам слова, а во вторых регулярка не работает в начале и конце строки :(

Comment: Решение нашел. Вот регулярка
~\b(пример)\b~i

Comment: Может быть, может быть. У меня получилось хуже (для utf8):

     ((?<!\p{L})|^)пример($|(?!\p{L}))

Comment: Стал пробовать и мой вариант оказывается не работает :( К сожалению Ваш у меня тоже выдает ошибку Unknown modifier '�' in

Comment: @savusha Обновил. Чую, что нужно @ReinRaus'a дождаться, его регулярки впечатляют своей находчивостью.

Comment: Эх, вроде банально должно быть, а не работает. Весь гугл перерыл. Нету. Неужели никому не нужно заменять целиковые слова а не части :)

Comment: @savusha кхм, у меня всё работает. Вот пример:
http://pastebin.com/4JTvFnur

Comment: А вот это "/(\s|^)(пример)(\s|$)/" кажись работает :) Буду пробовать, спасибо!

Comment: @savusha: не сработает на вот таком: "это пример, бэби!"

Comment: @VladD В вопросе условие: "А любые символы и цифры могут быть." А, тьфу, точно. Ща

Comment: @savusha Да уж. У меня вроде работает:

      echo preg_replace('/((?<!\p{L})|^)пример($|(?!\p{L}))/u','<а href="#">пример</а>','пример примеров,пример');
?>

       <а href="#">пример</а> примеров,<а href="#">пример</а>

Хотел с группами ненулевой длины, но там в случае "пример+пример" лажа

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\bпример\b/ui','<а href="#">пример</а>',$text);
```

Comment: Не, так вообще ничего не заменил :(

Comment: @ReinRaus добавьте, что файл должен быть в utf-8, иначе ничего не заработает. Ну лично у меня не заработало в cp1251.

Comment: А я думал, что все уже при сайтостроении используют utf-8, потому что cp1251 это прошлый век.

Answer (score 0):

то?

```
preg_replace('/\bпример\b/','<а href="#">пример</а>',$text);
```

или это?

```
preg_replace('/[^\s]*пример[^\s]*/','<а href="#">пример</а>',$text);
```

Тогда так?

```
preg_replace('/\s(пример)\s/', ' <a href="">пример</a> ',$text);
```

Может так?

```
preg_replace('/(\s|^)(пример)(\s|$)/','$1<а href="#">$2</а>$3',$text);
```

Comment: Не вышло, так по прежнему заменяет и в целых словах

Comment: @savusha обновил.

Comment: А второй вариант вообще обрубил все слова с таким вхождением до слова "пример"

Comment: @savusha обновил пост. Просто не сразу понятно, что вы хотите от регулярки.

Comment: Эх, в таком случае вообще ничего не заменят. Мне надо просто, что бы регулярка срабатывала в целых словах с точным совпадением, и не работала в частях больших слов со схожим содержанием. Уже и не знаю как подробнее описать :)

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил "$1". Регулярка заменяет, но на этот раз делает все слово ссылкой с таким вхождением, а не только его часть с точным совпадением.

Comment: @savusha обновил :D

Comment: `preg_replace('/(\sпример\s)/', '<а href="#">$1</а>', $text);`

Comment: @Palmervan а вы учли, что пробелы будут в ссылке?

Comment: @lampa, граница слова в понимании движка регексов это позиция:  

    (?<=\W|^)(?=\w) # начало слова
    (?<=\w)(?=\W|$) # конец слова
Русские символы входят в множество `\W` поэтому ни один из Ваших примеров скорее всего не сработает так, как надо. Чтобы добиться искомого надо сравнить с множеством русских символов или использовать POSIX выражения, которые понимают в юникоде где буква, а где нет почти для любой локали.

Comment: Извините. \b умнее чем кажется.  

    /\bпривет\b/iu
отлично работает.  
Мне минус @lampa плюс.

Answer (score 0):

[В помощь регуляркостроителка](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Накидал с помощью шаблон, думаю там надо дофига ньюансов вписывать:
[Здесь же](http://regexr.com?336ps)